# Problem with sound in wine and system

Tags: sound, wine

I tried to search for my problem, but couldn't find the solution...

Thus; I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, and PlayOnLinux to play Guild Wars 2... Rythmbox is always started on pause, as I like to use media buttons to play music whenever I feel like it...

It was all working fine, until (at some point, and I'm not sure what happened) I was not able to play music while I'm in game... So, I tried, and came to conclusion that, if I start the game with paused music, I won't be able to hear it play when I unpause it (it actually plays, but without any sound)... On the other hand, if I start music and then start the game, I will not be able to get any sound from game, even if I pause the music during the play...

I was looking through sound options in-game and fount out that if I play music before starting the game, my device list will have 3 rows:

- Default Device
- Out: HDA Intel PCH - ALC889 Digital ((null))
- Out: HDA Intel PCH - HDMI 0 ((null))

And if I start the game before music I will have 4 options:

- Default Device
- Out: HDA Intel PCH - ALC889 Digital ((null))
- Out: HDA Intel PCH - HDMI 0 ((null))
- Out: HDA Intel PCH - HDMI 0 ((null))

I use classic integrated audio card with 3.5mm audio jack pluged in into my VGA TV...
Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have notice the same issue.  It's the system sound or Wine sound just not both.  Once the game is running if I open the system sound program and goto the application tab there is no wine apps listed either way. Not sure if this is related but it seemed like it could be.  Was working until about a month ago on Ubuntu 12.04 with 1.5.12-GuildWars2 Play on linux wine version.  Tried with other versions and same problem.